# Insert multiple items into a database row and return the results separated by commas

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way to insert multiple items into a database row then return the results and their counter part as commas?

For instance:

```
POST
POSTID       URL                                              HITS
1            http://google.com,http://facebook.com            35,20
```

So say post 1 has the 2 urls in it, google has 35 hits, while facebook has 20.  now I want to show that result using something like:

```
$query = $db->query_first("
  SELECT * FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."post
  WHERE url = '" . $drc_url . "'
");
```

But I only want to pull one URL at a time with its corresponding hits value.  Is this possible?  If so can someone point me in the right direction?

right now my php looks like:

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."post WHERE url = '" . $drc_url . "'"); 
      if (!$query){ 
          $db->query_write("INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PREFIX ."redirect (url, hits) VALUES ('" . $drc_url . "', 1)");
      } else { 
          $db->query_write("UPDATE ". TABLE_PREFIX ."redirect SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE url = '" . $drc_url . "'"); 
      }
```

but if theyre in the same $postid I want them to all get put in the same row

Comment: Yes, but it's far easier if your normalize your data tables properly

Comment: As above, see normalization

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in code.

```
$drc_url = "http://google.com";

/* insert/update */
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."post WHERE url LIKE '%" . $drc_url . "%'");
if ( $query->num_rows > 0 ) {
    // the URL can be in multiple rows - go through each row
    while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
        //find the URL position/index within the list
        //if it's possible that the URLs are already separated by anything else than comma (for example "comma and space", "space", etc), you need to add functionality to be able to find them correctly
        $urls = explode( ',', $row[ 'url' ] );
        $index = array_search( $drc_url, $urls );
        //same as previous comment goes for the hits row
        $hits = explode( ',', $row[ 'hits' ] );
        //increment the hits number on the correct value
        $hits[$index]++;
        //update the hits (put them back as a string from the array with already incremented value) - use unique identificator in the WHERE clause
        $db->query("UPDATE ". TABLE_PREFIX ."redirect SET hits = '" . implode( ',', $hits ) . "' WHERE postid = '" . $row[ 'postid' ] . "'");
    }
} else {
    // the URL was not found - insert
    $db->query("INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PREFIX ."redirect (url, hits) VALUES ('" . $drc_url . "', 1)");
}


/* select */
//same functionality as above, just not updating
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ". TABLE_PREFIX ."post WHERE url LIKE '%" . $drc_url . "%'");
while( $row = $query->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $urls = explode( ',', $row[ 'url' ] );
    $index = array_search( $drc_url, $urls );
    $hits = explode( ',', $row[ 'hits' ] );
    echo "URL " . $drc_url . " has " . $hits[$index] . "hits";
}
```

---

But as Mark Baker wrote in the comment, it would be much better to change the DB structure and then build on the new structure.